# Using System.Reflection

Tags: reflection, c#-3.0

Im loading an Exe into my application using Assembly.LoadFile().
From that is it possible to get the Method of a particular class from that EXE.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:\path-to-some-app.exe");
    var desiredType = assembly.GetType("SomeNamespace.SomeClass");
    var methodInfo = desiredType.GetMethod("MethodName");
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of things you can do with Reflection (Including constructors, method invocation etc.) Tutorial at : http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/